# Range based for loop throws a compiler error with array parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Admittedly, I'm just finding my footsteps in C++ but I don't understand the error here.

The following error gets displayed:

`Error  1   error C3312: no callable 'begin' function found for type 'int []'`

`Error  2   error C3312: no callable 'end' function found for type 'int []'`

`Error  3   error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier`

`4  IntelliSense: this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found`

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArray(int[]);

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    printArray(a);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void printArray(int a[]) {
    for (int i : a) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

Can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 24):

Inside `printArray`, `a` is *not* an array! I know it looks like one, but it's not. `int a[]` there means `int* a`, due to a nasty legacy from the 1850s.

Here is the fix to your problem, passing in the array by reference and therefore keeping its full type (including numerical dimension):

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
void printArray(int (&a)[N]) {
    for (int i : a) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    printArray(a);
}
```

*(I've also removed some redundant code and that horrid `system("pause")`: properly configure your execution environment rather than having your program take responsibility for blocking its caller when it's finished!)*

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/339e1abbacd98aee))

Comment: 1850s?? Like, XIX century?

Comment: @EliaIliashenko Yep

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Explain how there wasn't computers

Comment: @EliaIliashenko B.C.

Comment: LoL   I like the reference to the 1850s  [ +1up]. It was also an elegant and simple answer, as are the other 5million answers of yours that I have read.

Comment: What is the legacy from the 1850s

Answer (score 11):

```
void printArray(int a[])
```

*Despite* that function seeming to accept an array, what it *actually* gets is a pointer to the first element of said array. This is unfortunately a fact of life in C++, due to it's origins based on the C language.

And, as a pointer itself has no size information about the underlying array, no iterators are available for it, so `begin` and `end` will not work.

There are ways to do this with templates but, in this case, I'd probably just bite the bullet and use a vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void printArray (const std::vector<int> &a) {
    for (int i : a)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main () {
    const std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    printArray (a);
    return 0;
}
```